# Get latest post from each category with post attachment in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

On the homepage of a wordpress install, I would like to display the latest post from each category with the category title, post attachment, post title, post excerpt, and post date.

The post attachment will always be a thumbnail version of the "featured image". The reason I wish to use the attachment and not the main image linked to the article, is we are using a plugin that alloows the editor to post a youtube link which overrides the featured image, so if I use "get_the_post_thumbnail" it pulls in the video instead of the image.

The code I am currently using from a mash up of solutions I have found is as follows:

```
        <?php


         query_posts('cat=3&showposts=1');
          if(have_posts()) :
            the_post();
            $images = get_children(array(
              'post_parent' => get_the_id(),
              'post_type' => 'attachment',
              'post_mime_type' => 'image',
              'orderby' => 'ID',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'numberposts' => 1
            ));
            foreach((array)$images as $key => $image){
              echo wp_get_attachment_image($key);
              echo "<a href='" . get_permalink() . "'>Link</a>";
            }
            the_excerpt();
          endif;
        wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

My problems with the above are as follows:

1) I cannot figure out how to get the category name (I could just hard code this and repeat the above for each category, but that seems like cheating).

2) When I repeat this code for the next category the image or permalink do not show up. I assume this is because I am repeating references or something like that, but I am too amateur with Wordpress to know.

Any help will be much appreciated. The final result is to look like this : http://www.tagdesignuk.com/lovethat/

Regards,

Kevin

UPDATE:

I have simplified this now, but still am a little stuck. I have removed the video plugin as I will find an easier way to do this later on, so now my only problem is pulling in the correct sized thumbnail.

I am using the following code:

```
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=1' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php the_date(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any ideas on how to change the thumbnail size? The documentation (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) says to use as follows :

```
<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $size, $attr ); ?>
```

but in the absense of a post ID it doesnt work... and I do not know how to format it correctly and cant find any reference to what I should be doing.

Many thanks,

Kevin

Comment: 1> you can query for multiple categories in one go
2> Seems very weird behavior, can you show the code?

Comment: I just simply repeat the code above changing the cat id, thats it. I am very new to wordpress as we normally build using our own cms with standard php, so I am not used to the wordpress functions at all. Could you give me an example of what you mean please? Many thanks!

Comment: query_posts( 'cat=1,2,3' ); would work as well or you can just specify which categories you do not want posts from like query_posts( 'cat=-1,-2' );

Answer (score 0):

you can query for all the categories with get_categories() and then use the name property. For examples you should look at the [Wordpress Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) for this function.